# I18n does not have missing keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i run rspec locally everything is path no errors, but when i make pull request and start run CI.yml as rspec in github workflow gives errors [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4irCo.png)

what's wrong ?

Comment: Not too sure but have you tried to check what those missing keys are in production ? (Ok to be honest there is no explanation considering your locale files are same in local and dev but well ..)

Comment: well,  I just merged to master branch the workflow tests passed. Anyway thank you for answer ^ ^